# Poisson Kernel and the Law of Cosines

Tags: complex-analysis

Reading through Titchmarsh's Theory of Functions he proves the [Poisson Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel) in two different ways. I am only reading the first one.

If $u(r,\theta)$ is harmonic on the  disk  $R\mathbb{D}$ then we can interpolate the value of $u$ inside from the value at the bounary:

$$ u(r,\theta) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{R^2 - r^2}{R^2 - 2rR \cos(\theta - \phi) + r^2}\; u(R,\phi) \;d\phi$$

Titchmarch comments this doesn't just follow from Cauchy Integral formula:

> These formulae are analogous to Cauchy's formula giving the residue of $f(z)$ at any point inside a contour giving the values on the Contour.  They cannot, however be obtained merely by separating the Cauchy formula into real an imaginary parts.

OK.  The proof goes by subtracting **two** instances of the Cauchy integral formula, and then taking real parts.

\begin{eqnarray}
u(z)+iv(z) &=& \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{u(w) + i v(w)}{w - z} dw  \\ \\
0 &=& \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{u(w) + i v(w)}{\overline{w}-\overline{z}^{-1}} dw  \\
0 &=& \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{u(w) - i v(w)}{\overline{w}-\overline{z}^{-1}} dw  \\
\end{eqnarray}

Then if we subtract the two contours, the Cauchy residue formula should fall out.

\begin{eqnarray} (u+iv)(z) &=&
 \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint (u+iv) 
\left[\frac{1}{w-z} \right]dw -
 \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint (u-iv) 
\left[\frac{1}{\overline{w}-\overline{z}^{-1}}\right]dw \\
&=&
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint
u(w) \left[\frac{1}{w-z} -\frac{1}{\overline{w}-\overline{z}^{-1}}\right] \, dw + \dots
\end{eqnarray}

Oh it seems I am getting myself into trouble.  It still looks nothing like Poisson integral formula.

---

My idea to simplify Titchmarsh's proof was to choose a rational function so the result come out from a single contour integral

$$ u+iv = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|= R} (u+iv) \frac{p(w)}{q(w)} \, dw$$

or at least find some "topological" intuition as to how the clockwise contour and counterclockwise contours should combine.